# JSX unreachable code at second <FilterItem> within

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator, jsx

So supposed that I have this JSON data:

```
{
  "product":
           [
            "Banana Moon",
            "Banana Republic",
            "Bec & Bridge",
            "Beldona",
            "Bench",
            "Caterpillar",
            "Cosmopolitan",
            "Cinderella"
           ]
}
```

And later, in a component, I have a function:

```
generateList() {
    var letter = '';
    var products = this.props.data.product;

    filterList = products.map(function (product) {
        return (
                (product.charAt(0) !== letter) ?
                    (
                    (letter = product.charAt(0)),
                    <FilterItem type="header" header={letter} field={filter}
                                count={products.filter(function(value) { return value.charAt(0) === letter}).length}/>
                    <FilterItem type="item" field={filter} name={product}/> // HERE

                    ) :
                    <FilterItem type="item" field={filter} name={product}/>
            )
        });
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve here in the ternary operator is that, if the product's first letter (i.e., Banana Moon), is not equal to the current `letter`, then the returned item will be two `FilterItem`, one a header which contains the current letter (i.e. "B") and the first `FilterItem`. Else, only the FilterItem is returned (i.e. Banana Republic, because it is the same with the current letter, no new header is needed).

As you could see, my ternary operator is quite complex. The `(letter = product.charAt(0))` first stores the current new letter to the variable `letter`, then the second clause returns the two `FilterItem`s.

But Webstorm warns that the second `FilterItem` is unreachable? And when I try running the code, it says there is an `Unexpected  token` error between the two `FilterItem`?

Is it not possible to return two React components in a ternary conditional operation?

PS. I tried converting it to `if-else` but it still gives the same error? Why is that?

```
filterList = products.map(function(product, key) {
    if (product.charAt(0) !== letter) {
        letter = product.charAt(0);
        var count = products.filter(function(value) { return value.charAt(0) === letter}).length;

        return (
            <FilterItem type="header" header={letter} field={filter} count={count} key={key}/>
            <FilterItem type="item" field={filter} name={product} key={key}/>
        )
    } else {
        return <FilterItem type="item" field={filter} name={product} key={key}/>
    }
```

Comment: "Is it not possible to return two React components in a ternary conditional operation?" --- it's not possible to return 2 react components at all. As of your code - just make it a normal if, it would be more readable and easier for you to make it working.

Comment: As I stated in the PS. @zerkms, I tried doing it through a normal `if-else`, but it still give the same errors.

Comment: Well, you tried it incorrectly, I suppose.

Comment: I updated it. Kindly inspect if I have coded it wrong @zerkms

Comment: You cannot return 2 components (from an expression), you must wrap them in some other component, like `<div>`

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that. Same goes for adding it to the `filterList` though I guess. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent needing a wrapping component, switch to a `forEach` and push to an Array rather than use `map`:

```
const filterList = [];
products.forEach(function(product, key) {
    if (product.charAt(0) !== letter) {
        letter = product.charAt(0);
        var count = products.filter(function(value) { return value.charAt(0) === letter}).length;
        filterList.push(<FilterItem type="header" header={letter} field={filter} count={count} key={key}/>);
        filterList.push(<FilterItem type="item" field={filter} name={product} key={key}/>);
    } else {
        filterList.push(<FilterItem type="item" field={filter} name={product} key={key}/>);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. Although I prefer a ternary conditional for it is coding-wise and shorter (and for me readable).

Comment: "To prevent needing a wrapping component" --- you still need to wrap a collection of components in something

Comment: @zerkms Right, an Array cannot be returned from `render`, but a ReactElement accepts Arrays as children. i.e. `<div>{filterList}</div>`

Comment: Yep, but have a look at the OP's code and the other deleted answer. "To prevent needing a wrapping component" cannot be eliminated in this case, you must wrap it with something. Not sure how the OP checked this answer if in the other answer they commented: "The filterList must contains continuous <FilterItem>s and encapsulating the header and first filter item would disrupt it"

Comment: The method in the code is called `generateList`, not `render`, so I assumed it was a secondary method whose return value was used somewhere in render. Something like `return <div>{this.generateList()}</div>`. Admittedly, I assumed a lot for my answer.

Comment: Hello guys. The `FilterItem` is encapsulated by a parent div, so that was one of the unexpected problem I saw and realized it late. The `{this.generateList()}` is under the parent `<div>`, so I solved it by returning the filterList instead at the end of the function.